# How can I count how many times a word is given in a user input sentence?

Tags: python

I have this homework to count how many times a word is given in a sentence, which a random user typed.

For example, for:

```
"I'm new to python and I have a problem"
```

the output should be:

```
I'm: 1
new: 1
to: 1
pyhton: 1
and: 1
I: 1
have: 1
a: 1
problem: 1
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: This is your homework, not ours. Read [ask] if you need help to solve a specific issue.

Comment: Also, "pyhton" doesn't exist in that string.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your input using the space caracter (' '), and create a dictionary matching all words with the count of it. After that, you can  print the result by iterating over the keys of the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
sen = "I'm new to python and I have a problem"
dic = defaultdict(int)
for i in sen.split():
    dic[i]+=1

for k,v in dic.items():
    print(' word:{} occurrence: {}'.format(k,v ))
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to explicitly use `str.split(' ')` as the [split method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) uses the whitespace character as separator by default.